# How to solve "No module named _bz2" error?

Tags: python-3.x, debian, python-s3fs

I'm trying to use `s3fs` in Python 3.6, using Debian 3.16.51-3.

When I import s3fs:

```
import s3fs

...
from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'
```

Alright, I tried to update/install `libbz2-dev`, as mentioned in other questions here in SO.

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  bzip2 bzip2-doc libbz2-1.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  bzip2-doc libbz2-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bzip2 libbz2-1.0
2 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 151 not upgraded.
Need to get 425 kB of archives.
After this operation, 561 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main bzip2 amd64 1.0.6-7+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.128.204 80]
Err http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libbz2-1.0 amd64 1.0.6-7+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.128.204 80]
Err http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main bzip2-doc all 1.0.6-7+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.128.204 80]
Err http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main libbz2-dev amd64 1.0.6-7+deb8u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.128.204 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/b/bzip2/bzip2_1.0.6-7+deb8u1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.128.204 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/b/bzip2/libbz2-1.0_1.0.6-7+deb8u1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.128.204 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/b/bzip2/bzip2-doc_1.0.6-7+deb8u1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.128.204 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/pool/updates/main/b/bzip2/libbz2-dev_1.0.6-7+deb8u1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.128.204 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Tried using `--fix-missing`, but reached the same error. Apparently the files are not available for download (?).

How should I approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you solve this issue? can you please share?